# Room Database operations inside flow function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Here is my login function that return a flow

```
override  fun loginMeIn(loginDto: LoginDto): Flow<Resource<User?>> = flow {
    emit(Resource.Loading())

    try {
        Log.e(TAG, "loginMeIn : try");
        val result = api.loginMeIN(loginDto)
          dao.deleteAll()
          dao.upsertUser(result.toUserEntity())
         val user = dao.getUsers().first()
        emit(Resource.Success<User?>(user.toUser()))
        Log.e(TAG, "loginMeIn : job finished");

    }catch (e:HttpException ){
        emit(Resource.Error<User?>(message = e.response().toString(),data = null))
        Log.e(TAG, "loginMeIn :"+ e);

    }catch (e:IOException){

        emit(Resource.Error<User?>(message = "Couldn't reach server, check Your internet connection",data = null))
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't reach server");
    }

}
```

with this implementation the app crash with error : Cannot access database on the main thread
and if i use coroutine scope for IO dispatchers i cant emit the Success result Please Help!

Comment: can u please share your Activity/Fragment code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch coroutine context to `Dispatchers.IO` when making DB requests:

```
val user = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    dao.deleteAll()
    dao.upsertUser(result.toUserEntity())
    dao.getUsers().first()
}
emit(Resource.Success<User?>(user.toUser()))
```

---

If you use Room DB you can try to mark functions as `suspend`, for example:

```
// in Dao class
@Insert
suspend fun insertUser(user: User)
```

If all function are marked as `suspend` then you won'y need to switch coroutine context to `Dispatchers.IO` in `flow` builder.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer i will check then i give you my feedback